# Questions on the SillyNameMaker Sample

Tags: actions-on-google

1. How does it know to transfer to the make_name intent after the Default Welcome Intent? What if I had another intent?
2. "What is your lucky number" seems to be duplicated in both the Default Welcome Intent and the make_name intent. Is this OK?

Answer (score 2):

About 1), the Default welcome Intent says `Hi! Welcome to Silly Name Maker! Let's get started. What is your lucky number?` which asks the user for a number. The user will then answer a number by saying `23` or `My lucky number is 23` and as you can see in make_name those are the trainings phrases. This means that the make_name intent will be triggered and receive the **number** parameter.

If you had another intent, you would have added training phrase to it and modify your text in the welcome intent accordingly so that you can direct your user to trigger it.

Concerning 2), in the default welcome intent it's the text answer and in make_name it's the text answer **IF** the required parameters `number` is not specified.

I.e., if your user answers your default welcome intent with `My lucky number is` the the app will ask `What is your lucky number` to get the parameter value because the number is missing.